# What's the purpose of blocking SIGCHLD before fork()?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, kernel, fork

I am reading several shell implementations. One thing that confuses me is it seems very common to block SIGCHLD before spawning a child process and unblock it right after `fork()` in both parent and child processes.

What is the purpose of doing that? What will happen if I don't block this signal?

Answer (score 0):

So bascially, it is used to avoid the race between parent and child. This can make sure the sigchild handler won't be received before parent executing something.